# DateTime comparison fails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

For some reason, the comparison always fail, please check this out from Rails console :

```
irb(main):021:0> @game.game_date.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
irb(main):026:0> @game.game_date
=> Tue, 19 Feb 2013 23:15:00 UTC +00:00
irb(main):022:0> @game.game_date.to_datetime
=> Tue, 19 Feb 2013 23:15:00 +0000
irb(main):019:0> DateTime.now
=> Tue, 19 Feb 2013 23:48:38 +0330
irb(main):020:0> @game.game_date.to_datetime > DateTime.now
=> true
```

How come that the comparison is always wrong? I tried this as well:

```
@game.game_date.to_time > Time.now.to_tim
```

The result was true as well , while it's obvious that it is supposed to be false since 23:48 > 23:15:00.

Please note that i'm using ruby ruby 1.9.3p0 under ubuntu and Rails 3.1

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: `@game.game_date.to_datetime > Time.zone.now` instead (using your timezone)

Comment: tried , the same result, which is true. Time.zone.now gave me (Tue, 19 Feb 2013 20:47:24 UTC +00:00) and @game.game_date.to_datetime (Tue, 19 Feb 2013 23:15:00 +0000)

Comment: DateTime.now gives the time in your timezone. So in this case timezone is `+0330` which means the current UTC time will be `Tue, 19 Feb 2013 20:18:38 +0000` which is less than `Tue, 19 Feb 2013 23:15:00 +0000`.

Comment: Can you recommend me how to handle it and to compare it with DateTime.now ? or how ti set a new timezone just to be something like DateTime.now result or even anyways to disable the timezone somehow ? I just want the result to be false somehow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a problem with the TimeZone:

```
irb(main):022:0> @game.game_date.to_datetime
=> Tue, 19 Feb 2013 23:15:00 +0000
irb(main):019:0> DateTime.now
=> Tue, 19 Feb 2013 23:48:38 +0330
```

You see, your game_date attribute has a `+0000` TimeZone, when DateTime.now has a `+0330`

Try this:

```
@game.game_date.to_datetime > Time.zone.now
```

Comment: same result, true , Time.zone.now gave me (Tue, 19 Feb 2013 20:47:24 UTC +00:00) and @game.game_date.to_datetime (Tue, 19 Feb 2013 23:15:00 +0000)

Comment: Well, its true there that 20:47 is earlier than 23:15. isn't it?

Comment: well, u r right, but how am I supposed to change it, i mean to set time zone ?

Comment: is there anyways to disable timezone, i just need the result Time.zone.now = Time.now somehow so the result will be false

Comment: Try `Time.zone.now.to_s(:db)` @EkiEqbal

Comment: same result, true, @game. game_date.to_datetime => Tue, 19 Feb 2013 23:15:00 +0000, and Time.zone.now.to_s(:db) => "2013-02-19 21:02:59"

Comment: Look I tried something like @game.game_date.to_datetime > Time.now.to_datetime.change(:offset => "+0000") and I got what I was expecting which is false but do u think it is right to use it this way ?

Answer (score 0):

It worked to me this way, anyways not sure if it is the best way but at least working the way I'm expecting it :

```
@game.game_date.to_datetime > Time.now.to_datetime.change(:offset => "+0000")
```